# How to use GPT-4 to help authors write a document with LaTeX formatting?

Tags: gpt

I read in OpenAI's [GPT-4 Technical Report](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.08774.pdf):

> GPT-4 was used in the following ways: to help us iterate on LaTeX formatting [...]

How can one use GPT-4 to help authors iterate on LaTeX formatting?

---

Note that the training data of GPT 3.5 or 4 definitely included source code texts. [Example](https://chat.openai.com/share/d6c3208f-234a-4811-9cc5-eaf6367b3c1a) ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRAam.png)) --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBigy.png

Comment: I think that you can limit the scope of this question by detailing the expected output. Do you want to convert some text to the LaTeX format? Or get the LaTeX code for a math formula? Etc.

Comment: @A.L thanks, I am open to any ways using GPT-4 to make it more efficient to format a document in LaTeX.